# Django 1.3 - BooleanField to DateTimeField Migration Fails

Tags: django, postgresql, migration, django-south

Working with Django 1.3 on Postgres 9.1.

I've been tasked with migrating two old bool fields `pulled` and `mail_report` to timestamps.

In attempting to migrate I get the following error, that I'm not sure how to get around outside of manually removing a non-Null constraint in the database to allow me to cast all of my records to null.
`django.db.utils.DatabaseError: column "pulled" cannot be cast to type timestamp with time zone`

Any insight getting around this that doesn't involve me manually tinkering with our live database would be appreciated.

Model declaration changes:

```
     # Reporting Checked Flags
     # pulled => Object has been processed through order_picklist
-    pulled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
+    pulled = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
     # mail_report => Object has been processed through report_mailing_list
-    mail_report = models.BooleanField(default=False)
+    mail_report = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

Comment: I think it would be better to do this in two separated migrations: first, drop the two columns from your models, and second, recreate them with the new types.

Comment: @PauloBu I suppose my only trouble with that is I need to save state of the existing bools, so I can add a datetime.now() stamp to all that  are currently flagged as true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [the `Data Migration` section in the South's docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations). There, they teach you how to change a plain-text password to a hashed one. To accomplish this, they need to retain the value of the current passwords and convert them.

My advice is to go, step by step with migrations likes this:

1. Create new `datetime`s column with names: `pulled2`, `mail_report2`
2. Create a data migration to populate this columns depending on the boolean value in their respectives columns `pulled` and `mail_report`
3. Create another migration to delete boolean columns `pulled` and `mail_report`
4. Create a last migration to rename `pulled2` and `mail_report2` to `pulled` and `mail_report`

Hope this outline and [the tutorials](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/index.html) in the docs be helpful!

Comment: This would work fine, and I used this conceptually to get what I needed. Unfortunately, we have to pre-rig these transactions such that our live server is down as little as possible, meaning I can't take the time to migrate, change source, migrate. So I used a raw query to avoid Django's query args validation to fetch a list of ids, dropped the old one, created a new one, and iterated over the list of id's to initialize them. Thanks for getting me thinking in the right direction.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you could make it anyways :)